# JSON Schema - How to specify an object that contains anything?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I've got a JSON schema:

```
{
  "required": ["name", "description"],
  "properties": {
    "name": { "type": "string" },
    "description": { "type": "string" },
    "meta": { "type": "object" }
  }
}
```

How do I specify that the `meta` nested object can contain absolutely anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just leave the schema empty:

```
{
  "required": ["name", "description"],
  "properties": {
    "name": {"type": "string"},
    "description": {"type": "string"},
    "meta": {}
  }
}
```

If you don't specify any constraints, then anything goes!